# Re writing Category Argument

Tags: categories

I have a theme which has a category argument, however its displaying them in the wrong order

```
<?php  

            $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=types&title_li='); foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>
```

I want it to display this in the slug say for example so that they can be in order.

Would it be a case i add the following argument?

```
  <?php  

            $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=types&title_li=' 'orderby'  => 'name',); foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>
```

this is the full category query, is just putting it in the wrong order:

```
<?php  $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=types&title_li='); foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>

<?php //print_r(get_term_link($category->slug, 'types')) ?>

            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category->slug, 'types') ?>" class="<?php echo $category->category_nicename;?>" data-type="<?php echo $category->category_nicename;?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) explains this pretty well.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'slug', // or name
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'types'
);
$categories=  get_categories( $args );
?>
```

Comment: would i just be able to replace this then vancoder? this is a theme that i brought but its not arranging them

Comment: I would do this in a child theme, otherwise your changes would be overwritten next time the theme is updated.